# When to use duration vs delay in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, data-visualization

I'm trying to learn some transitions for d3, and I'm stuck on what the difference between `duration` and `delay`.  I have the code working, and with a fixed time or a callback function the transitions appear identical if I switch between the two.

Is there any real difference between the two? Should I not be using duration with a callback?  What's best practice for when to use one over the other?

```
     svg.selectAll('circle')
        .transition()
      /*
        .duration(function(d, i){
            return d.r * 75 
        })
      */
        .delay(function(d, i){
            return d.r * 75 
        })
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return xScale(d.x);
        })
        .style('fill', 'orange')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`duration`**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#duration) specifies *how long* the transition should run.

[**`delay`**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#delay) is the time *after* the transition should start.

Comment: Ohh, okay that makes a lot of sense.  The documentation wasn't too clear, and I guess I was using times that were to small to notice the difference.  Thank you for your help!